# Splitting a list of lists in half randomly

Tags: python, list

Trying to make a card game in python, I made a list called a "cardlist", which contains 52 lists as "cards". What I´m trying to do now is to make 2 new lists for the user and computer to use in the game, and they have to contain a random half of the cards. I´m not sure how to do this.

```
import random
class Lamb():
    def __init__(self, weight, milk, wool, offs, thigh, fert, meat, fat):
        self.weight = weight
        self.milk = milk
        self.wool = wool
        self.offs = offs
        self.thigh = thigh
        self.fert = fert
        self.meat = meat
        self.fat = fat

   def __repr__(self):
       return f"{self.weight,self.milk,self.wool,self.offs,self.thigh,self.fert,self.meat,self.fat}"

def Read(txtfile):
datalist=[]
f = open(txtfile, "r", encoding="utf-8")
for line in f:
    datalist.append(line.split(','))
f.close()
cardlist = []
for i in datalist:
    cardlist.append(Lamb(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3], i[4], i[5], i[6], i[7]))
return cardlist
```

Comment: You can `random.shuffle` and split down the middle.

Comment: also if every line only has the information you want, it's much neater to write:
`for line in f: cardlist.append(Lamb(*line.split()))`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about maintaining the original sorting of `cardlist`, you can simply shuffle it, then give the first half to the user and the second half to the computer:

```
random.shuffle(cardlist)
split = len(cardlist) // 2
user_deck = cardlist[:split]
computer_deck = cardlist[split:]
```